# Put up link or 301 entire site for bigger SEO Boost

Tags: seo

I have two sites with no content (currently they are parked). The URL is keyword rich/premium for the term we are targeting and cost us a couple thousand each. They each have pagerank of 1 mostly because they have some age and some minor link building and old SEO firm did. is it better to

```
A. 301 these sites to our current site. 

B. Put up a few pages of content and link to our site.
```

A third option for one of them would be to create a blog out of one and link to our site from it sometimes but I am mostly wondering what would pass more authority A or B. Also thinking of putting of some content doing some more link building, letting them sit for a bit and then redirecting.
Consider that both domains are parked now with no real content, and that the URLs are keyword rich.

Comment: Either one- do not expect much. Exact match keyword domains do not really count for anything. 301 redirects would only make sense if the sites have been active all this time, if they have been sitting with no content, then the value has dropped rapidly. As well, I never recommend maintaining several sites for a single purpose. If you want your current site to rank well, then work on it. Make it something that people want. But do not think that adding more sites helps. It generally makes things worse. Sites that have been sitting ignored are heavily discounted by SEs as being abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Either one- do not expect much. Exact match keyword domains do not really count for anything. 301 redirects would only make sense if the sites have been active all this time, if they have been sitting with no content, then the value has dropped rapidly. As well, I never recommend maintaining several sites for a single purpose. If you want your current site to rank well, then work on it. Make it something that people want. But do not think that adding more sites helps. It generally makes things worse. Sites that have been sitting ignored are heavily discounted by SEs as being abandoned.